# Integrate PayPal IPN in Symfony Application

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to implement PayPals IPN in my Symfony Application. Users can buy credits in their account settings and they can pay them through PayPal. 
Now i want to receive Paypals Instant Payment Notification messages to be immediately informed, when the payment was successfuly.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IfwYMI25L8) Video Tutorial here and integrated that code in my Symfony application. I made that action available through the link myproject.com/advertiser/account/paypalnotification.

The thing is, when i try to use the IPN Simulator and enter the url and use the transaction type "Web Accept" i get the error: "We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error".

The reason why is that this simulation gets an 500 status code due to a CSRF Token mismatch.

Anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Solution found. If you have an htaccess file which needs http authentication the ipn simulator is not going to work. 

So check that you have deactivated your http authentication.

Comment: Consider writing the solution you found as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then accepting it (you should be able to do that after a few days): it will be more visible that way than as a comment.

Comment: Take a look at the OmnipayBundle and PayumBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an htaccess file which needs http authentication, the IPN simulator wont work. 
Please make sure you disable HTTP authentication when you test PayPal IPN